# Installer manifest embedding problems

Tags: windows, winapi, installation, manifest

I have my own installer application. In order to elevate permissions to admin I have this RC file:

```
2 ICON "icon.ico"
1 RT_MANIFEST "setup.exe.manifest"
```

And following manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
      <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows Vista functionality -->
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
      <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 7 functionality-->
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 8 functionality-->
        <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
      <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 8.1 functionality-->
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
    </application> 
  </compatibility>

  <asmv3:trustInfo xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <asmv3:security>
      <asmv3:requestedPrivileges>
        <asmv3:requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </asmv3:requestedPrivileges>
    </asmv3:security>
  </asmv3:trustInfo>

</assembly>
```

The installer is compiled using MSVC 2017, then I append the actual data to install to the setup.exe file. I assume the beginning of the EXE file contains info about its original length, so system can read anything it needs and won't actually touch appended data. The icon is displayed correctly, so I assume things are working fine.

But I have 2 problems:

1. On some computers (which unfortunately I don't have, I only have reports) the OS doesn't seem to actually elevate the permissions and the installer fails to write some files.
2. On many computers after the installer ends the system displays the famous "This software hasn't been installed correctly..." window.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: If the installer is then "run as administrator" via right-click menu, it finishes without problems.
Edit2: The installer is also signed and the signature is correctly read by Windows.

Comment: Which OS versions does it fail to elevate and what is the UAC setting on those systems?

Comment: I actually have no idea - but from some brief info from the customers it seems related to some newest Windows 10 with default UAC settings.

Comment: And "doesn't not seem to elevate" means they don't get a UAC elevation dialog at all?

Comment: I'm not sure, but they didn't say anything about it. I'll ask when the next one comes in.

Comment: You are building this with MSVS2017 - The project build settings already include parameters that will be written to an automatically generated and included manifest.

Comment: Are you sure that your manifest is embedded into executable? Maybe your setup program is elevated because its name contains "setup" phrase (or "install", "inst" etc). It looks that in Windows 10 1709 this heuristic ceased to work.

Comment: @ChrisBecke I was originally using VS 2013, now I switched to VS 2017, so I'm not sure about the situation yet, but I didn't really use the "embed manifest" stuff.

Comment: @DanielSęk I have no idea, is there a way to find out? I was exactly thinking about this.

Comment: "*The installer is compiled ... then I append the actual data ... The installer is also signed*" - are you appending to the installer before or after the installer is signed? Do it before, as altering the EXE after signing will invalidate the signature. also, the signature is located at the end of the EXE, so if you blindly append data after the signature, Windows won't be able to validate the EXE anymore unless you take extra measures to "fix" that (see [Changing a Signed Executable Without Altering Windows Digital Signature](https://blog.barthe.ph/2009/02/22/change-signed-executable/)).

Comment: I do it in this order, anyways the method below works. Not sure what is the problem with the RC file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently embedding it as resource like this just doesn't work. One can use this command to verify the manifest:

```
mt.exe -inputresource:blablabla.exe;#1 -out:extracted.manifest
```

But it works when used directly from the Linker / Manifest file page inside MSVC, without an actual manifest file, it generates some itself.

Comment: "*Apparently embedding it as resource like this just doesn't work.*" - yes, it does. I do it all the time with other non-VC compilers and it works just fine.

Comment: Well, maybe I did something wrong, hard to say, that's why I described what I do in the question. And well, it doesn't work :).

Comment: My guess would be that your project settings are set to have the compiler/linker create its own manifest that ends up overwriting your custom manifest resource. To verify, use a resource viewer/editor to view the actual manifest that ends up in the final compiled EXE. If you want to use a custom manifest, you should turn off the compiler/linker generated manifest. Or, simply don't use a separate custom manifest file at all. Place your custom manifest elements in the project settings and let the compiler/linker merge them with its own manifest elements to produce the final manifest resource.

Comment: Good point! The exe actually doesn't seem to contain a manifest at all. Anyways it's fine, all I needed was the admin rights. Thanks for the insight!